# can i install 64bit ubuntu os in my laptop which runs on 32bit windows 7 home premium

Tags: system-installation

I have a laptop with the following:

- Windows 7 home premium 32-bit
- Pentium Dual-core CPU T4300 @ 2.10GHz
- 4GB RAM

Can I install Ubuntu-14.04.3 64bit?

Answer (score 4):

Running a 64 bit version of any operating system is primarily dependent on the processor the computer is using and whether it supports the 64 bit instruction set. If we look on Intel Ark ([Source](http://ark.intel.com/products/37253/Intel-Pentium-Processor-T4300-1M-Cache-2_10-GHz-800-MHz-FSB)) for the model of CPU in the laptop it shows that it has support for `Intel 64` which states that:

> Intel® 64 architecture delivers 64-bit computing on server,
>   workstation, desktop and mobile platforms when combined with
>   supporting software.¹ Intel 64 architecture improves performance by
>   allowing systems to address more than 4 GB of both virtual and
>   physical memory.

This means that the CPU can handle 64 bit software such as operating systems and supporting applications.

Comment: Please tell me how to find it

Comment: How to find what?

Comment: To find out that my computer is competable or not

Comment: The source I provided in the answer states that the processor inside your laptop supports 64 bit operating systems and thus should be able to run 64 bit code, that's all there is to it.

Comment: Thank you sir for patiently answering my questions,thank you very much sire

Answer (score 1):

**Yes you can.**
there are two ways you can install 64Bit Ubuntu in your laptop machine.

1. **WMWARE:**

Install vmware in your windows OS, you can use other virtual machine software too, like `Oracle Virtual Box`, `Microsoft VM` the best is VMWARE.

after installation you can either install Ubuntu from `ISO` or can download already installed Ubunut Vmware files and just use it.

2. **Native Ubuntu:**

Better to install Ubuntu OS along side windows OS on another physical partition rather than Virtual Machine.

Boot from Ubuntu ISO USB/CD/DVD and choose "Something Else" on installation screen. then select or create new partition for Ubuntu. and let the installation begins.

Comment: VMWare: You can run 64 bit in a 32 bit OS on a 64 bit machine but not on a 32 bit machine unless it has that Vx option. QEMU can emulate a 64-bit processor though.

Comment: yes, after core 2 due technologies you'll see most of machines are 64bit.

Comment: Brothers please tell me that can I install 64 bit on my laptop when it has 32bit Windows 7 running

Comment: @DarkLord you already have the answer?! See the 1st 3 words of this answer. +1 LukyBiy -Ku :-)

Comment: @DarkLord the installation is pretty easy. just install vmware or vmware player (more easy) and with it open your downloaded [Ubuntu vmware image](http://www.osboxes.org/vmware-images/)